# Script, remove asking ? and just delete

Tags: google-apps-script

not good with Google scripts, just wondering how i could change this part to just delete instead of asking if i want to delete, basically just say yes.

```html
// Remove any calendar events not found in the spreadsheet
  var numToRemove = calEventIds.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
    if (curVal !== null) {
      prevVal++;
    }
    return prevVal;
  }, 0);
  if (numToRemove > 0) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.Button.YES;
    if (numToRemove > numUpdated) {
      response = ui.alert('Delete ' + numToRemove + ' calendar event(s) not found in spreadsheet?',
          ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    }
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
      calEventIds.forEach(function(id, idx) {
        if (id != null) {
          calEvents[idx].deleteEvent();
          Utilities.sleep(20);
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the delete method inside the `if (numToRemove > 0) {` block provided that is your condition before deleting your items, so it would looks something like:

```
if (numToRemove > 0) {  
  calEventIds.forEach(function(id, idx) {
    if (id != null) {
      calEvents[idx].deleteEvent();
      Utilities.sleep(20);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works, I just moved your code into the if statement.

```
// Remove any calendar events not found in the spreadsheet
var numToRemove = calEventIds.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
  if (curVal !== null) {
    prevVal++;
  }
  return prevVal;
}, 0);

if (numToRemove > 0) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.Button.YES;
  if (numToRemove > numUpdated) {
    calEventIds.forEach(function(id, idx) {
      if (id != null) {
        calEvents[idx].deleteEvent();
        Utilities.sleep(20);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i used the answer after yours just because i come to it first, but thanks for your help.